# Matlab vertical line keeps appearing while using hold on and area()

Tags: matlab

It is beginning to annoy me that I can't get rid of this vertical line that keeps appearing when I plot the area;

```
[x y] = ginputExtra(4)

x =    0.1947    0.6118    0.8329    0.4136    
y =    0.5746    0.8173    0.4225    0.3553

area([x x(1)],[y y(1)])
[x y] = ginputExtra(4,true)

x =    0.5087    0.6881    0.4954    0.3204    
y =    0.4961    0.2382    0.1566    0.3566

hold on;
area([x x(1)],[y y(1)],'FaceColor',[1 0 0])
```

[image: Area plot]

Is there any way to avoid this line?

BTW: the ginputExtra method call I use..

```
function [x y] = ginputExtra(n,booText)
% INPUT
% n:            Number of points to plot
% booText:      Boolean (default false) command to display point number in
%               the plot.

% Author:   Lasse Nørfeldt (Norfeldt) 
% Date:     2012-04-09

if nargin ==2
    bText = booText;
else
    bText = false;
end
H = gca;
set(H, 'YLimMode', 'manual'); set(H, 'XLimMode', 'manual');
set(H, 'YLim', get(H,'YLim')); set(H, 'XLim', get(H,'XLim'));

numPoints = n; xg = []; yg = [];
for i=1:numPoints
    [xi yi] = ginput(1);
    xg = [xg xi]; yg = [yg yi];
    if i == 1
        hold on;
        plot(H, xg(i),yg(i),'ro');
        if bText text(xg(i),yg(i),num2str(i),'FontSize',14); end
    else
        plot(xg([i-1:i]),yg([i-1:i]),'r');
        if bText text(xg(i),yg(i),num2str(i),'FontSize',14); end
    end    
end
hold off;

x = xg; y = yg;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue might be in plotting by area(), as it seems to be primarily for stacking several vecotrs. If you zoom out a bit and see a similar vertical line from the first point in the blue area, the area function is most likely the issue.

The function:

```
fill([x x(1)],[y y(1)],COLOR)
```

Might do the trick for you, as it plots a filled polygon.

/Thomas

Comment: Was trying that, but couldn't make it work at the time.. But now it's working just fine.. weird.. But thank you very much for the help.